# Alternative Proof for Rudin RCA's Theorem 2.17(b)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

> $\bf 2.17\ $ **Theorem** $\ $ *Suppose $X$ is a locally compact, $\sigma$-compact Hausdorff space. If $\frak M$ and $\mu$ are as described in the statement of Theorem $\it 2.14$, then $\frak M$ and $\mu$ have the following properties:*
>
> $(a)\ \ $ If $E\in\frak M$ and $\epsilon>0$, there is a closed set $F$ and an open set $V$ such that $F\subset E\subset V$ and $\mu(V-F)<\epsilon$.
> $(b)\ \ $ $\mu$ is a regular Borel measure on $X$.
> $(c)\ \ $ If $E\in\frak M$, there are sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ is an $F_\sigma$, $B$ is a $G_\delta$, $A\subset E\subset B$, and $\mu(B-A)=0.$

**My proof/approach to (b) is different from that of the author**, and I would like to know if it's correct (and please fill in gaps if you see any). Here it goes:

By Riesz representation theorem, $\mu$ is already outer regular for all sets, and inner regular for all open sets and sets $E$ with $\mu(E) < \infty$. Consider $E\in\mathfrak M$ such that $\mu(E) = \infty$. Since $X$ is $\sigma$-compact, $X = \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^\infty K_j$ where $K_j$'s are compact. So we can write $$E = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty (E\cap K_j)$$
Now, $E\cap K_j$ has finite measure for every $j$, since $E\cap K_j \subset K_j$, and $\mu(K_j) < \infty$ since $K_j$'s are compact. I want to show $$\mu(E) = \sup\{\mu(K): K\subset E, K \text{ compact}\}$$ in order to show inner regularity w.r.t. sets of infinite measure. I write $E = \lim_{n\to\infty} E_n$, where $E_n = \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^n (E\cap K_j)$. Clearly, $E_n \to E$ as $n\to\infty$. Since $\mu$ is a measure, $\mu(E_n)\to \mu(E)$ as $n\to\infty$. Note that $\mu(E_n) < \infty$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, since $E\cap K_j$ has finite measure for every $j$. Since we already have inner regularity for sets with finite measure, we can write $$\mu(E_n) = \sup\{\mu(K): K\subset E_n, K \text{ compact}\}$$
Since $E_n\subset E$, $K\subset E_n \implies K\subset E$. By definition of supremum, we can find a compact set $K\subset E_n\subset E$ such that $\mu(K) > \frac{\mu(E_n)}{2}$. Why? Suppose this wasn't the case, then for every compact $K \subset E_n$, $\mu(K) \le \frac{\mu(E_n)}{2}$. This cannot happen, since $\mu(E_n)$ (and not its half) is the supremum over all such compact sets $K\subset E_n$. However, $\mu(E_n) \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$, since $\mu(E) = \infty$. $\mu(K) > \frac{\mu(E_n)}{2}$ would then mean $\mu(K)\to\infty$ as well. Hence, the supremum of
$\{\mu(K): K\subset E_n, K \text{ compact}\}$ is $\infty$, which is nothing but $\mu(E)$. $\square$

---

Is the proof above correct? I may have missed a couple of things, in which case, feel free to correct or add to the above writeup. Thanks a lot!

---

P.S. By Theorem 2.14, the author means Riesz Representation Theorem.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Specfy which book of Rudin you mean please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct.  It can be slightly simplified at the end. Here it is.

**Proof**: By Riesz representation theorem, $\mu$ is already outer regular for all sets, and inner regular for all open sets and sets $E$ with $\mu(E) < \infty$. Consider $E\in\mathfrak M$ such that $\mu(E) = \infty$. Since $X$ is $\sigma$-compact, $X = \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^\infty K_j$ where $K_j$'s are compact. So we can write
$$E = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty (E\cap K_j)$$

Now, $E\cap K_j$ has finite measure for every $j$, since $E\cap K_j \subset K_j$, and $\mu(K_j) < \infty$ since $K_j$'s are compact. We want to show
$$\mu(E) = \sup\{\mu(K): K\subset E, K \text{ compact}\}$$

in order to show inner regularity w.r.t. sets of infinite measure. We write $E = \lim_{n\to\infty} E_n$, where $E_n = \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^n (E\cap K_j)$. Clearly, $E_n \to E$ as $n\to\infty$. Since $\mu$ is a measure, $\mu(E_n)\to \mu(E)$ as $n\to\infty$. Note that $\mu(E_n) < \infty$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, since $E\cap K_j$ has finite measure for every $j$. Since we already have inner regularity for sets with finite measure, we can write
$$\mu(E_n) = \sup\{\mu(K): K\subset E_n, K \text{ compact}\}$$

Since $E_n\subset E$, if $K\subset E_n$ then $K\subset E$. By definition of supremum, given any fixed $\varepsilon$, we can find a compact set $K_n\subset E_n\subset E$ such that $\mu(K_n) > \mu(E_n) -\varepsilon$. However, $\mu(E_n) \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$.  So $\mu(K_n)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ as well, and we know that, for all $n$, $K_n \subset E$. Hence,
$$\sup\{\mu(K): K\subset E, K \text{ compact}\} = \infty = \mu(E)$$
which completes the proof. $\square$